# What is server email address?

Tags: php, email, email-validation

I am trying to use verifyEmail PHP library in my application.

I am following [this](https://github.com/hbattat/verifyEmail/blob/master/README.md) link.

I am confused with this following line:

```
Initialize the class:

$ve = new hbattat\VerifyEmail('some.email.address@example.com', 'my.email.address@my-domain.com');

The first email address 'some.email.address@example.com' is the one to be checked, and the second 'my.email.address@my-domain.com' is an email address to be provided to the server. This email needs to be valid and *from the same server that the script is running from*.
```

What does "email from same server..." mean?

Comment: This basically means is, if your website is say `example.com` then, the second parameter should be `user@example.com` of the same domain, same server, which should be valid and working email address.

Answer (score 2):

If you find that library too hard to use, you can try the following:

https://www.mailboxvalidator.com/php

To install via Composer:

```
"require": {
    "mailboxvalidator/mailboxvalidator-php": "1.0.*"
}
```

Sample usage:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use MailboxValidator\SingleValidation;

$mbv = new SingleValidation('PASTE_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE');

$results = $mbv->ValidateEmail('example@example.com');

if ($results === false) {
    echo "Error connecting to API.\n";
}
else if (trim($results->error_code) == '') {
    echo 'email_address = ' . $results->email_address . "\n";
    echo 'domain = ' . $results->domain . "\n";
    echo 'is_free = ' . $results->is_free . "\n";
    echo 'is_syntax = ' . $results->is_syntax . "\n";
    echo 'is_domain = ' . $results->is_domain . "\n";
    echo 'is_smtp = ' . $results->is_smtp . "\n";
    echo 'is_verified = ' . $results->is_verified . "\n";
    echo 'is_server_down = ' . $results->is_server_down . "\n";
    echo 'is_greylisted = ' . $results->is_greylisted . "\n";
    echo 'is_disposable = ' . $results->is_disposable . "\n";
    echo 'is_suppressed = ' . $results->is_suppressed . "\n";
    echo 'is_role = ' . $results->is_role . "\n";
    echo 'is_high_risk = ' . $results->is_high_risk . "\n";
    echo 'is_catchall = ' . $results->is_catchall . "\n";
    echo 'mailboxvalidator_score = ' . $results->mailboxvalidator_score . "\n";
    echo 'time_taken = ' . $results->time_taken . "\n";
    echo 'status = ' . $results->status . "\n";
    echo 'credits_available = ' . $results->credits_available . "\n";
}
else {
    echo 'error_code = ' . $results->error_code . "\n";
    echo 'error_message = ' . $results->error_message . "\n";
}
?>
```

An API key is required but you can sign up for a free API key at below:

https://www.mailboxvalidator.com/plans#api

Answer (score 1):

You should use this class like this :

```
$ve = new hbattat\VerifyEmail('email.to.check@domain.com', 'my.email@domain.com');
```

So you need a Smtp server configured with "my.email@domain.com" ready to send emails.

Regards